# Custom keyboard crash only on galaxy s6+

Tags: java, android, keyboard

This is the error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.view.textservice.SpellCheckerSession.getSentenceSuggestions(android.view.textservice.TextInfo[],
>   int)' on a null object reference  at
>   com.allegretti.tastiera.free.MyKeyboard.updateCandidates(MyKeyboard.java:788)
>     at
>   com.allegretti.tastiera.free.MyKeyboard.handleCharacter(MyKeyboard.java:856)
>     at com.allegretti.tastiera.free.MyKeyboard.onKey(MyKeyboard.java:761)

My code:

```
private boolean isSentenceSpellCheckSupported() {
    return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN; } 

private void updateCandidates() {
    if (!mCompletionOn) {
        if (mComposing.length() > 0) {
            if (isSentenceSpellCheckSupported()) {

                ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                //list.add(mComposing.toString());
                Log.d("SoftKeyboard", "REQUESTING: " + mComposing.toString());
                mScs.getSentenceSuggestions(new TextInfo[]{new TextInfo(mComposing.toString())}, 5);
                setSuggestions(list, true, true);
            }else{
                mScs.getSuggestions(new TextInfo(mComposing.toString()), 5);
            }
        } else {
            setSuggestions(null, false, false);
        }
    } }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @Simze please read the title , it not like other questions

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: @PavneetSingh in almost cases it would be similar, definitely some object would be null and OP is trying to access it.

Comment: Why only in the galaxy does not work?

Comment: @Simze yeah huge possibility you are right ,  but why only this `galaxy s6+` , i actually not sure so letme confirm some things with OP and with google first

Comment: Have you tested this on some other marshmallow devices other than 6+

Comment: @PavneetSingh on my wiki ridge 4g 5.1, Galaxy s6 simulator and Galaxy s6+! not work in the s6+

Comment: if possible than try it on real device with marshmallow or above and try reading about `getSuggestions` to make sure you didn't miss anything

Comment: Did you find the solution?